# What's the use of cache in csv type provider?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I am a bit confused about `Cache` and `CacheRows`.

It seems `MyCsvType.Load(path).Take(30000).Cache()` doesn't actually read the 30000 rows immediately. (unlike `Seq.cache`)

Then, why do we need `Cache` given we have already `CacheRows`

Additionally, if I am only interested in the first 30000 rows, should I use `MyCsvType.Load(path).Take(30000)` or  `MyCsvType.Load(path).Rows |> Seq.take 30000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at F# Data source code, you can see that `Cache`, `Take` and other operators are just calling the corresponding `Seq.xyz` operations under the cover (this is [in CsvRuntime.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/fe5ba3afab12d855b9a9739387719b101dde6d21/src/Csv/CsvRuntime.fs#L349)).

The key difference is that when you create a type provider without specifying `CacheRows=false`, it will actually call `Cache` by default. So, the trick is to create a type provider using `CacheRows=false` and then you can use `Seq.cache` or the `Cache` method (and other operations) interchangeably.

```
let stocks = CsvProvider<"sample.csv", CacheRows=false>.GetSample()
stocks.Take(10).Cache()             // Using methods is now exactly
stocks |> Seq.take 10 |> Seq.cache  // the same as using functions
```